# Connecting flights between Newark Liberty and JFK -- what to do with layover?

Tags: public-transport, layovers, ewr, jfk

I have 4.5 hours between when my plane lands at EWR (domestic) and departs JFK (international).

Google Maps says the train trip from EWR to JFK is about 1.5 hours.

Do I have enough time for a quick bite to eat in Manhattan?  Or is that pushing it?

Is there a preferred train line?

(This will be in mid-December.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For international flights I usually try to be at the airport 2-3h before departure. So adding approx. 45min for EWR - Manhattan and approx. 45min for Manhattan - JFK, there wouldn't be much time left for to eat anything besides a quick meal in McDonald's.

Comment: Thanks.  This is basically what my wife and I concluded after more discussion.